# Independence of linear combinations of (normal) random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If $X_1$, $X_2$, and $X_3$ are independent normally-distributed random variables, and $a_1, a_2$ are constants, does it follow that $(a_1 X_1 + a_2 X_2)$ and $X_3$ are independent? It seem obvious, but I can't easily think of a proof.

Comment: They are independent if and only if they are uncorrelated.

Comment: @StubbornAtom is this because they are normally distributed?

Comment: Yes, because $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ is jointly normal.

Comment: What about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent?

Comment: You have to distinguish between mutually independent and pairwise independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If random variables $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are mutually independent (not just pairwise independent), then the $\sigma$-algebras $\Sigma_1, \Sigma_2, \Sigma_3$ they generate are independent.  Normality is not needed.
Since $a_1 X_1 + a_2 X_2$ is measurable with respect to the $\sigma$-algebra generated by 
$\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$, and this and $\Sigma_3$ are independent, $a_1 X_1 + a_2 X_2$ and $X_3$ are independent.

On the other hand, if $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$ are only assumed to be pairwise independent, it's not true.  A standard example is this:

Let $X_1, X_2, Y$ be  jointly normal random variables with means $0$ and covariance matrix $I$.  Let
$$ X_3 = \cases{Y & if $X_1 X_2 Y \ge 0$\cr
               -Y & otherwise} $$
Then $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$ are standard normal random variables which are pairwise independent, but $X_1 X_2 X_3 \ge 0$.

Now $X_1 + X_2$ and $X_3$ are not independent.  In fact, consider the covariance
of $(X_1 + X_2)^2$ and $X_3$.
$$\text{Cov}((X_1+X_2)^2, X_3) = \text{Cov}(X_1^2, X_3) + \text{Cov}(X_2^2, X_3) + 2\text{Cov}(X_1 X_2, X_3)$$
The first two terms are $0$ because of pairwise independence, but the third term is positive because $X_1 X_2 X_3 > 0$ with probability $1$.